# Drupal 7 - Search From

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, recipe

I'm using Recipe Module in my Drupal 7 site. Each recipe contains the list of ingredients. Now i know how to create a view to search the Recipe which has the ingredients. I did this by using filter in Drupal views. by the same way i need to omit some ingredients from the result. I mean exclude the listed ingredients from the Search result. Is this can be done in drupal views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ingredients are terms in a vocabulary, you can determine the list of ingredients that may be searched for in an exposed filter.

Comment: Those are not terms in the vocabulary.

Comment: Well, what type of field you are using then? A simple textbox with pre-defined values?

Comment: In getting the field from the content type. I did that by Adding "Filter Criteria" -> Filter by "Recipe" -> added the field " Recipe: Ingredient Name"

Comment: I meant to ask how the ingredients are stored when creating a recipe. Obviously, you do not select them from a list?

Comment: And all ingredients go into one single textfield? Or is it set up as a textfield with multiple values?

Further, do you want to restrict the display of certain ingredients in the result list or omit them from the filter?

Comment: multiple text field..One text-field will have one ingredient oly. I need to omit from the filter.

Comment: if i use operator "is equal to" in the filter.. It shows the search result with the recipes which has the given ingredients. When i change operator to "not equal to" then while searching the receipes without the ingredient.. the behaviour is strange.. it show duplicated result of recepie... if the recipe has 3 ingredients then its listed 3time. if 4ingredients then 4times listed.

Comment: There's no way then to do it through Views UI. Since there's no list of allowed values, Views UI can't offer you to exclude/include anything.

Comment: I would recommend to set up the ingredients as vocabulary terms.

Comment: then how can i attain this functionality in drupal 7?

Comment: You would need to write a custom module (eventually with an admin interface to easily adjust the list of ingredients to exclude) which has to hook into the search queries and remove the ingredients you don't want the user to be able to search for.

Comment: So, then anonymous user's can't added new ingredient right? because if we make that as vocabulary terms then it would be like a list box

Comment: If you have three recipes:
Strawberry Milkshake (Strawberries, Milk, Crushed Ice),
Caipirinha (Cachaca, Limes, Crushed Ice),
Strawberry desert (Strawberries, Milk, Vanilla) ...

And say you want to exclude "Crushed Ice" from search filter, should the user still be able to find Strawberry Milkshake when searching for "Strawberries"?

If not, you could enable two filters: 1) is hidden and set to exclude "Crushed Ice", 2) is exposed.